# Grails spring-security - Can I intercept before success action to check required password change?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

Upon creating new users in my system, I am sending them a temporary password via email and setting an property of changePasswordNextLogin=true.  When they come to log in for the first time, I would like to intercept the flow upon a successful login, check for this this value, and if it is true, redirect them to a change password action.  Once the password change has been completed, ideally I would like to send them to their intended destination.

I have been pouring through the default settings and am not seeing - or more likely not interpreting properly - any way to make that happen.  It seems that almost every time that I try to cobble some solution together in Grails, I find that someone has already made a much more elegant approach to do the same thing.  Is there any functionality built in that would allow this?

If not, I would really appreciate any suggestions on the best approach to make it so.

Comment: are you using the spring security core plugin? Or some other plugin or maybe your own filters? If you are using the spring security plugin, then the @darrend provided the basis for using the passwordExpired property provided by the framework.

Comment: @omarello the question text didn't mention s2, but it was tagged as such, so I thought it was a safe assumption :)

Comment: Sorry to both of you.  I assumed that having "Grails spring-security" in the title of the post was descriptive enough, but I didn't consider the idea of using S2 without the plugin. I guess I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some support for this directly with Spring Security and the grails plugin, but you also have to do some work yourself :)

The domain class that was created when you installed grails-spring-security plugin (and ran the S2Quickstart script) has a property on it named 'passwordExpired'.  Set this to true when you create your new user domain instance.

Once that user logs in for the first time, the Spring Security core libs will throw an exception which you can catch in your login controller's authfail closure, re-directing them to the change password form (that you need to supply yourself).

Here's an example from one of my apps, a skeleton version of this closure should already be included in your login controller:

```
/**
 * Callback after a failed login.
 */
def authfail = {

    def msg = ''

    def username = 
       session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY]

    def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]

    if (exception) {
        if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired")
            if (!springSecurityService.isAjax(request))
                redirect (action:'changePassword') // <-- see below
        }
        // other failure checks omitted
    }

    if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
        render([error: msg] as JSON)
    }
    else {
        flash.message = msg
        redirect controller: 'login', action:'auth', params: params
    }
}

/**
 * render the change pwd form
 */
def changePassword = {
    [username: session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY] ?: springSecurityService.authentication.name]
}
```

From your 'changePasssword' view, submit the form back to another controller closure (I call mine 'updatePassword' that checks whatever constraints you want for passwords and either saves the updated password on the domain object or not..

```
def updatePassword = {
    String username = session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY] ?: springSecurityService.authentication.name
    if (!username) {
        flash.message = 'Sorry, an error has occurred'
        redirect controller: 'login', action:'auth'
        return
    }
    String password = params.password
    String newPassword = params.password_new
    String newPassword2 = params.password_new_2
    if (!password || !newPassword || !newPassword2 || newPassword != newPassword2) {
        flash.message = 'Please enter your current password and a new password'
        render view: 'changePassword', model: [username: username]
        return
    }
    SecUser user = SecUser.findByUsername(username)
    if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, password, null /*salt*/)) {
        flash.message = 'Current password is incorrect'
        render view: 'changePassword', model: [username: username]
        return
    }
    if (passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, newPassword, null /*salt*/)) {
        flash.message = 'Please choose a different password from your current one'
        render view: 'changePassword', model: [username: username]
        return
    }
    if (!newPassword.matches(PASSWORD_REGEX)) {
        flash.message = 'Password does not meet minimum requirements'
        render view: 'changePassword', model: [username: username]
        return            
    }

    // success if we reach here!
    user.password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(newPassword)
    user.passwordExpired = false
    user.save() 

    flash.message = 'Password changed successfully' + (springSecurityService.loggedIn ? '' : ', you can now login')
    redirect uri: '/'
}
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for.  I really appreciate you taking the time to explain. Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Secuirty 3.0 and later, You can refer to the spring security plugin documentation [11.3 Account Locking and Forcing Password Change](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/passwords.html).
Remember that you should set 
`grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.storeLastUsername=true` in Config.groovy.