# Grails - Intercepting entered Username in LoginController's authfail

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to force a user to change his password on the first login (as has been discussed here [Grails spring-security - Can I intercept before success action to check required password change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923429/grails-spring-security-can-i-intercept-before-success-action-to-check-required)).

However, neither `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY` (which is also deprecated) nor `springSecurityService.authentication.name` does provide the entered username. All I get is `__grails.anonymous.user__` what can't be used to set the user's new password.

Does anyone of you have an idea how to determine the entered username?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out how to pass on the username entered in the login form to the `changePassword.gsp`. Nevertheless, I constructed a workaround which is not perfect yet but at least is working.

The `authfail` closure in my custom login controller stays as has been presented in [Grails spring-security - Can I intercept before success action to check required password change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923429/grails-spring-security-can-i-intercept-before-success-action-to-check-required)

However, I deleted the `changePassword` closure because I added a textfield in the `changePassword.gsp` to enable the user to enter his username. That's also the reason why I think that this solution is not perfect, because normally I would not like to have to re-enter my username as well.

As I'm quite new to grails, some of you may have a hint or two on how to realize this functionality more elegant. I would really appreciate it :)

Following the source extracts for `LoginController` and `changePassword.gsp`.

`LoginController.groovy`:

```
/**
 * Callback after a failed login. Redirects to the auth page with a warning message.
 */
def authfail() {

    String msg = ''
    def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]
    if (exception) {
        if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.expired")
        }
        else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired")
            if (!springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
                flash.message = msg
                render view: 'changePassword'
                return
            }
        }
        // omitting other cases
    }

    if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
        render([error: msg] as JSON)
    }
    else {
        flash.message = msg
        redirect action: 'auth', params: params
    }
}

def updatePassword() {
    String username = params.username

    if (!username) {
        flash.message = 'Sorry, an error has occurred'
        redirect controller: 'login', action:'auth'
        return
    }

    String password = params.password_old
    String newPassword = params.password_new
    String newPassword2 = params.password_new_rep

    if (!password || !newPassword || !newPassword2 || newPassword != newPassword2) {
        flash.message = 'Please enter your current password and a new password'
        render view: 'changePassword', model: [username: username]
        return
    }

    User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username)

    if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, password, null /*salt*/)) {
        flash.message = 'Current password is incorrect'
        render view: 'changePassword', model: [username: username]
        return
    }

    if (passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, newPassword, null /*salt*/)) {
        flash.message = 'Please choose a different password from your current one'
        render view: 'changePassword', model: [username: username]
        return
    }

    if (user.username.equals(newPassword)) {
        flash.message = 'New password must not equal your username'
        render view: 'changePassword', model: [username: username]
        return
    }

    // success if we reach here!
    user.password = newPassword
    user.passwordExpired = false
    userService.updateUser(user)

    springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username, newPassword)

    flash.message = 'Password changed successfully' + (springSecurityService.loggedIn ? '' : ', you can now login')
    redirect uri: '/'
}
```

`changePassword.gsp`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="general" />
        <title>Change password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <content tag="heading">Change password</content>
        <content tag="content">
            <g:if test="${flash.message }">
                ${flash.message }
            </g:if>
            <g:form name="changePassword" autocomplete="off">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><g:field type="text" name="username" required="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Old password</td>
                    <td><g:field type="password" name="password_old" required=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>New password</td>
                    <td><g:field type="password" name="password_new" required=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>New password (repeat)</td>
                    <td><g:field type="password" name="password_new_rep" required=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <g:actionSubmit name="submit" value="Change password" action="updatePassword"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </g:form>
        </content>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').focus();
});
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `session.getAttribute(SpringSecurityUtils.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY)`
Also I had to enable this property in config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.storeLastUsername=true
```